# How to limit number of Toplevel windows in tkinter

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I have a bit of code that creates a a top level window upon the user
pressing a button.

However i would like to limit the number Top level windows to one, so the user couldn't Spam the button and open fifty windows.

```
import tkinter as tk

class app():

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.master = master    
        master.configure(background = '#002e3d')
        master.title('Test!')
        master.geometry = master.geometry('660x550+200+200')
        master.resizable(width = False,height = False)
        self.button = tk.Button(master,text = 'Test'command = self.searchmenu)
        self.button.pack()

    def searchmenu(self):
        Demo()


class Demo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel()
        self.top.title('Search!')


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    window = app(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the user wants to open 50 windows, why stop him? Perhaps he has reasons that you can't anticipate, why should you add code to needlessly restrict the user? Also, code that you don't write has – by definition – zero bugs.

Comment: If @msw's clever comment went over your head: from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic   `Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.` Although you need to do this regardless of whether it is for homework or not.

Comment: Thank you. i will take what both of you said into consideration.

Comment: I have an application (GSP5) that when I open a file that is already open, it opens a copy and warns me that it is a copy so I have to close it and find the original amongst the several windows I have minimized.  `IDLE` which is built with `tkinter` instead brings the already open one to the top.  Considering making a copy once the original is open is very easy, which behaviour is more desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a reference to the `Demo` object you create (which I'd recommend regardless) this becomes very trivial task:

```
class app():

    def __init__(self,master):
        ...
        self.popup = None

    def searchmenu(self):
        if self.popup is None:
            self.popup = Demo()
```

Although once the created window is destroyed this doesn't allow to reopen it, so you may want to also check if the top still exists with `winfo_exists()`:

```
def searchmenu(self):
    if self.popup is None or not self.popup.top.winfo_exists():
        self.popup = Demo()
```

EDIT: if the popup is already open then pushing the button should `lift` it to the top of the window stack:

```
def searchmenu(self):
    if self.popup is None or not self.popup.top.winfo_exists():
        self.popup = Demo()
    else:
        self.popup.top.lift(self.master)
```